# Passing a Variable Number of Arguments to a C Function

Tags: c, sockets, methods

Didnt know how best to describe this but ill explain here.
I want to be able to do what i can do with `printf` I.E
`printf("Variable:%@",astring);`

to call the below method i would run `write_sock(sock,"my message but i want a variable in here a well");`

Does that make sense?

```
static void write_sock(int sock, const char *msg)
{
    int len = strlen(msg);
    if (write(sock, msg, len) != len)
    {
        perror("short write on socket");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `snprintf` or, if your OS supports it, `asprintf`. These are used to print, just as `printf` does, into a string. If you are on mac or linux `man 3 printf` will tell you of all the different versions of these functions.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about the use of variable arguments... (note: vasprintf() may or may not be available... I'm just using it for illustration here)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

static void write_sock(int sock, const char *msg, ... )
{
    va_list args;
    va_start( args, msg );
    char* newMsg;

    vasprintf( &newMsg, msg, args );

    int len = strlen(newMsg);
    if (write(sock, newMsg, len) != len)
    {
        perror("short write on socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    free( newMsg );

    va_end( args );
}
```

Comment: `vsprintf` is standard, you could use that, too.

Comment: I think you may have to include `<stdarg.h>` before you get the `v` versions of the functions. Entirely from memory though.

Comment: True... but `vsprintf()` requires you to have an existing buffer for you to write into (and that you won't overflow it). Conversely, if `vasprintf()` exists, it will allocate the buffer for you and you need not fear overflowing it.

Comment: if `vasprintf` doesn't exist then `vsnprintf` should be your first fall-back.

Comment: @Will -- according to the man pages for `vasprintf()`, it only requires `<stdio.h>` -- however... yeah... ~smile~

Comment: @KScottPiel I checked my system's manpage in the meantime too. It seems that you don't need to on Mac. I suppose you may need to on some systems. You will need the header some time if you actually plan on using the functions so I don't suppose the order of them really matters too much.

Comment: @KScottPiel: An existing buffer would be better. Use the return value from `vsnprintf()` to check if the buffer was large enough and do `realloc(needed + spare)` and retry if it wasn't. This way the buffer auto-adjusts to a good size (not too large and not too small) and you avoid doing `malloc()` then `free()` every single time.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`sprintf(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/sprintf/):

```
char buffer[100];
sprintf(buffer, "Variable: %d", x);
write_sock(sock, buffer);
```

Comment: No problem.  KScottPiel has a more sophisticated solution, if you want, too.

Comment: Probably better to use `snprintf` if it's available.

Comment: Probably, yes.  I think it's standard.